# Not able to resolve feign client name from application yml

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, feign

I have a spring boot app and i am trying to use feign client to make a request to an endpoint but its not able to resolve feign client name from application yml.
My application yml has following code :

```
ribbon:
  eureka:
   enabled: false
beacon:
  ribbon:
    isSecure: true
    listOfServers: https://beacon.org
```

My interface look like this :

```
@FeignClient("beacon")
public interface BeaconClient {

    @GetMapping("/api/organizations")
    List<Org> getOrgs();

}
```

I am getting an error 500 internal server error because i see that it making a request to http://beacon/api/organizations endpoint instead of https://beacon.org/api/organizations

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The default feign Logger is misleading. `http://beacon/..` that you see in the log isn't indicative of actual url that is being called. The actual request is resolved with `https://beacon.org/..`.